# Mongodb - 'self learning' indexes?

Tags: mongodb

It's the first time I use Mongo's schema-less design, storing Documents with different (unpredictable) structure, in the same collection. Usually I'd avoid this, but I need it for a special requirements.

```
// John stores pruducts, with pricing-related fields:
db.myCol.insert({owner:"john", price:100, discount:5})
// Mary stores color preferences:
db.myCol.insert({owner:"mary", color:"green", background:"white"})
```

Naturally John will query on price / discount, while Mary will query on colors. 
Note **Queries have a very simple structure of "AND".**

The problem is indexes - I can't tell in advance what fields users would store/query.

Currently I can live with manually checking the logs every now and then, and manually adding/removing indexes. But it occurred to me I'm probably not the 1st to run into the problem - so is there any option for 'self learning' indexes, automating my manual job? E.g. automatically detect many slow queries with "color" (assuming they're a simple AND structure), and add index accordingly.

I'd appreciate any pointers, either within Mongo, or external tools.
So far the most creative idea I found was changing the document structure so that I could use array indexes (effectively indexing everything), but I'd appreciate it if there are more elegant solutions.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably want to do is "learn" to understand the types of queries that are being performed in order to know which fields to index.

I would suggest setting the [profiling leve](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel/)l and doing some log analysis in order to make some decisions over the "commonly" used fields and combinations.

```js
db.setProfilingLevel(2)
```

And that will log **all** operations.

You might also be interested in [this contribution](https://github.com/rueckstiess/mtools) by one of the MongoDB employees.

This [mtools](https://github.com/rueckstiess/mtools) suite is actually used "in-house" by various employees to aid in log analysis.

Worth giving a try.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't tell in advance what fields users would store/query

Smells like a key-value store to me.

The beauty of this is that you can dynamically index an arbirary number of fields and data and search on them, i.e. user defined fields.

As an example, your document would be:

```
{
    _id: {},
    owner: 'John',
    fields: [
        price: 100,
        discount: 5
    ]
}
```

And you would make an index on the fields key of your document and you would query for the users dynamic fields by using `$elemMatch`.

Of course that is just one way of setting up a key-value store, the one you would be most used to seeing is where you store the keyname and value as values with the keys `k` and `v`.

This also allows you to query for the actual names of these fields along with a couple of other niefty things.

So a key-value store could be exactly what your looking for here.

#### Edit

I ironically didn't actually read:

> So far the most creative idea I found was changing the document structure so that I could use array indexes (effectively indexing everything), but I'd appreciate it if there are more elegant solutions.

Unfortunately even in techs that arr designed for these kind of queries (Memcached being one) they actually take on this structure, effectively indexing an array, it is merely hidden from you.

Comment: Thanks very much, at least by confirming this approach you've saved me hours of futile hunting after non-existent alternatives. Sincerely appreciated :)